# "You don't think it's poisonous, do you?" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was watching a TV series where a kidnapped person was told by her kidnapper after seeing she didn't eat her lunch:

> You don't think it's poisonous, do you?!

Then he demonstrated to her that it wasn't poisoned by taking a bite. Is that expression used -here and in general- to express that you think the person being spoken to believes the first part or the opposite?

## edit-1:@Liron Ilayev:

To clarify things,the kidnapper wasn't the bad person and in a sense neither was the "victim", the "victim" killed people who were "based on  bogus" information going to commit acts of mass murder, the kidnapper was a detective who wanted to link the source of the bad information to the murders of the would be "killers", hence he kidnapped the "victim" to force her to see he errors of her ways and to show her that the information she received was bogus and that she was deceived and to convince her to help him bring down the source of the information who used her.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meaning of "is there" in a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83330/meaning-of-is-there-in-a-sentence)

Comment: As pointed out in an answer to the linked duplicate, *[adding a tag question]* [***turns it into a statement instead of a question***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/83334/126). But in such contexts, the *meaning* of that question is effectively that the addressee is being invited to ***agree*** with the preceding "statement". Which by implication implies that if they ***don't*** agree, the speaker is telling them they are mistaken (because the statement ***is / should be*** true; the addressee would be wrong to think it was poisonous).

Comment: In practice, it wouldn't make any difference here if the speaker had used the opposite (non-negated) statement - *You think it's poisonous, don't you?* (notice that a tag question *always* inverts / negates the verb in the preceding statement). In both cases, we know pragmatically that the addressee is ***probably*** at least "suspicious", but unless the speaker deliberately accentuates the statement by introducing a heavily-stressed auxiliary (as in *You **do** think it's poisonous, don't you?*), we can't assume she has a confident opinion about what the addressee ***really*** thinks.

Answer (score 2):

Given the context of a kidnapper and a kidnapee, the sentence you are asking about sounds more as taunting rather than anything else. I imagine him smiling smugly as he asks that; it's just the vibe I, and I believe others too, receive from their relationship.

In most other contexts, however, the sentence is much more conversational. The person asking the question is deliberating with the other about the poisoning status of the food. An example might help make things clearer.

Two friends, Danna and George, sit for a brunch at a coffee shop where one of the workers is an old adversary of George's. George notices that person in the kitchen and mentions that person's enmity towards him. Their meal is served by the waiter, and given this context, Danna asks George, "You don't think it's poisonous, do you?" Dana is deliberating with George, both are not sure whether this is true, they discuss it together.

All in all, as to your question, the person being spoken to usually don't have a clue whether the first part (in this instance, whether the food is poisoned or not) is correct.

Comment: In short, it's nothing but a simple question. Aside from implied meaning in some contexts and from tones of voice (where it might be rhetorical), it means exactly what you'd think it means. It's an inquiry.